# Updating pandas dataframe if new data exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update my current dataframe with some data obtained from an API.

my stored data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "B", "C"], "balance":[100, 200, 300]})
```

my obtained data:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"name":["B", "C"], "balance":[400, 600]})
```

The results I am trying to get is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "B", "C"], "balance":[100, 400, 600]})
```

Is there a way to do that using python and pandas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `append` and then remove duplicates

```
df = df.append(df_new).drop_duplicates('name', keep='last', ignore_index=True)
df
  name  balance
0    A      100
1    B      400
2    C      600
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can make use of `concat()` and `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
resultdf=pd.concat((df,df_new),ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset='name',keep='last',ignore_index=True)
```

Now if you print `resultdf` you will get your desired output:

```
    name    balance
0   A       100
1   B       400
2   C       600
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df.balance = df.name.map(df_new.set_index('name').balance).fillna(df.balance)

df

  name  balance
0    A    100.0
1    B    400.0
2    C    600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge on `name` column

```py
df['balance'].update(pd.merge(df, df_new, on='name', how='outer')['balance_y'])
```

```
# print(df)

  name  balance
0    A      100
1    B      400
2    C      600
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `isnin`

```
indexs = df[df.name.isin(df_new.name)].index
df.loc[indexs,"balance"] = df_new["balance"].values

df
  name  balance
0    A      100
1    B      400
2    C      600
```